# Store dynamic number of entries in one table to a single row in another table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table called `users` with the following columns:

```
| id | name |
```

Then another table called `images` which looks like this:

```
| id | fileName |
```

What is the best way to assign a dynamic number of image rows to a to multiple user rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to your images table. For example, change your images table to have three columns:

```
| id | fileName | userID |
```

This userID must be one of the id values that already exists in the users table, otherwise this column would be pointless. This column will point back to the users table and essentially assigns each image to a specific user. Since one user can have many paintings, we call this a one-to-many relationship.

If you already have the tables created, you can try and run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE images ADD userID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE images ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(id);
```

The first line will add the column, while the second line makes the constraint for it. The constraint ensures that new rows added to the images table *MUST* have a valid userID. If you try and add a row with a userID that does not exist, you will get an error (and rightfully so, because images shouldn't belong to imaginary users).

This will also set the userID column of all existing image rows to 0. You may want to change this later, but that depends on your individual case.